# Getting multiple aggregations in Single statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

The table has data of city and its branchs/atms

```
CITY        TYPE       NAME
 ----------------------------------
 agra         atm         X
 agra         branch      X1 
 delhi        atm         X2
 agra         atm         X3
 agra         atm         X4
 delhi        branch      X5
 chennai      branch      X6
```

The result set expecting is

```
CITY     ATM   BRANCH
------------------------------------
agra       3       1 
delhi      1       1
chennai    0       1
```

Whether we can do this in one select statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this as with conditional summations in an aggregation:

```
select t.city,
       sum(case when type = 'atm' then 1 else 0 end) as ATM,
       sum(case when type = 'branch' then 1 else 0 end) as branch
from t
group by t.city
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know in advance all the values that you'll have for columns, then you can hardcode them in your query. Otherwise it gets a lot more complicated. Here it is in Oracle SQL:

```
with my_data as
    (select 'agra' city, 'atm' "type", 'X' "name" from dual union
    select 'agra' city, 'branch' "type", 'X1' "name" from dual union
    select 'delhi' city, 'atm' "type", 'X2' "name" from dual union
    select 'agra' city, 'atm' "type", 'X3' "name" from dual union
    select 'agra' city, 'atm' "type", 'X4' "name" from dual union
    select 'delhi' city, 'branch' "type", 'X5' "name" from dual union
    select 'chennai' city, 'branch' "type", 'X6' "name" from dual)

select city,
    sum(decode("type", 'atm', 1, 0)) as ATM,
    sum(decode("type", 'branch', 1, 0)) as branch
from my_data
group by city;
```

If the number of columns is unknown, Oracle has a '[PIVOT XML](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506)' statement that allows it to return all of the summarized data in one XML:

```
select * from my_data
PIVOT XML (count("name") for "type" in (ANY));
```

You can parse each column out yourself using the [EXTRACTVALUE()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions052.htm) function, but this still implies that you know how many columns there are ahead of time. I believe that Oracle SQL doesn't have the ability to create a pivot table with a dynamic number of columns. It can be done in PL/SQL though, where you'd use a cursor to dynamically concatenate your SQL.

Comment: @Annjawn: The WITH clause is possibly misleading; it is just a way of creating a 'temporary table' that contains the data you showed (with the usual anonymous table — it is weird how often SQL questions omit the table name(s)).  You would not need to key that in your real database; you'd just select directly from your table.  You'd write the SQL starting with the SELECT in column 1.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you should do in MS Access:

```
TRANSFORM Count(Table1.Name) AS CountOfName
SELECT Table1.City
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.City
PIVOT Table1.Type;
```

I guess PLSQL isn't that different, it also has the "pivot" clause available

**EDIT**:

In PL/SQL by using pivot

```
select * from (
    SELECT city, type FROM t ) 
       PIVOT(count(*)  for (type) in ('atm', 'branch'));
```

Comment: I think the tags say `oracle` `plsql`.

Comment: welcome, (i don't know any PL/SQL, so please forgive my question), but why do you need to list the various types in your list ? (atm, branch), isn't it the strength of PIVOT that you can dynamically create columns based on row values ?